# Node app restarting on load - digitalocean

Tags: node.js, server, digital-ocean

I've seen the pm2 logs and report and there I'm getting **JavaScript heap out of memory** but I've increased the heap limit to 12 GB and also added GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false into the environment variables. Locally, by just increasing the max-old space I've resolved the issue but on the server, getting the same error.
After consuming ~2.5GB of memory, my node app is getting restarted

Node: 12.22.12
RAM: 8GB

Added NODE_OPTIONS and GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false

Answer (score 0):

in Pm2 config file, there is a max memory reload settings

```
// ecosystem.config.js
module.exports = {
  apps: [{
    name: 'api',
    script: 'api.js',
    max_memory_restart: '10000M' // change this
  }]
}
```

Comment: I've already set max_memory_restart: 15G

Comment: module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'ABC',
      script: 'dist/main.js',
      instances: 1,
      autorestart: true,
      watch: false,
      max_memory_restart: '15G',
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
      },
    },
  ],
};

Answer (score 0):

I was facing node app restart because of the pm2... Earlier, I had set max_memory_restart: '2G' so pm2 cached that value and when I changed it into the '15G' pm2 didn't get that.
Simply do pm2 kill and deploy your app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).